# Update ManyToMany multiply rows in association table - Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I am doing app where I have `Product`, `Recipe`, `Menu`.

Table `Product` has `id`, `name`, `category` columns.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "category")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;
}
```

Table `Recipe` has id, `name`.

```
@Table(name = "recipes")
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "product2recipe",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")})
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

Table `Menu` has `id`, `name`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menus")
public class Menu {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "recipe2menu",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id")})
    private List<Recipe> recipes;
}
```

I connect Product-Recipe with table `product2recipe`, and Recipe-Menu with `recipe2menu` table.

`Recipe` can contains many `Products`, and `Product` can be in many `Recipe`s so it is ManyToMany relationship.
`Menu` contains many `Recipes`, and `Recipes` can be in many `Menu`s so it is also ManyToMany relationship.

To add `product`, `recipe`, `menu` to DB I am using `JpaRepository<Product(Recipe/Menu), Long>`

I created service to manage `Menu`:

```
@Service
public class MenuServiceImpl implements MenuService{

    private MenuRepository menuRepository;
    private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Menu> getMenus() {
        return menuRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Menu createMenu(String name) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.setName(name);
        menu = menuRepository.saveAndFlush(menu);
        return menu;
    }

    @Override
    public Menu getMenu(long id) {
        Menu menu = menuRepository.findById(id).get();
        return menu;
    }

    @Override
    public Menu addRecipe(long menuId, long recipeId) {
        Menu menu = menuRepository.findById(menuId).get();
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findById(recipeId).get();
        List<Recipe> rs = menu.getRecipes();
        rs.add(recipe);
        menu.setRecipes(rs);
        menu = menuRepository.saveAndFlush(menu);
        return menu;
    }
}
```

And wrote test:

```
@Test
    public void shouldCreateSingleMenuAndUpdateAddedTheRecipes() {
        Assertions.assertThat(menuRepository.findAll()).size().isEqualTo(0);
        Assertions.assertThat(recipeRepository.findAll()).size().isEqualTo(0);
        Assertions.assertThat(productRepository.findAll()).size().isEqualTo(0);
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("rod");
        product.setCategory(Category.FRUIT);
        productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);

        Product product2 = new Product();
        product2.setName("rod2");
        product2.setCategory(Category.NONE);
        productRepository.saveAndFlush(product2);

        Product product3 = new Product();
        product3.setName("rod3");
        product3.setCategory(Category.VEGETABLES);
        productRepository.saveAndFlush(product3);

        Recipe recipe1 = new Recipe();
        recipe1.setName("r1");
        recipe1.addProduct(product);
        recipe1.addProduct(product2);
        recipe1.addProduct(product3);

        recipe1 = recipeRepository.saveAndFlush(recipe1);

        Recipe recipe2 = new Recipe();
        recipe2.setName("r2");
        recipe2.addProduct(product3);

        recipe2 = recipeRepository.saveAndFlush(recipe2);

        Recipe recipe3 = new Recipe();
        recipe3.setName("r3");
        recipe3.addProduct(product3);
        recipe3 = recipeRepository.saveAndFlush(recipe3);

        Menu menu1 = menuService.createMenu("m1");

        menuService.addRecipe(menu1.getId(), recipe1.getId());
        menuService.addRecipe(menu1.getId(), recipe2.getId());

        Menu menu1AfterAddRecipe = menuService.addRecipe(menu1.getId(), recipe3.getId());

        Assertions.assertThat(menu1AfterAddRecipe.getRecipes())
                .extracting("name")
                .containsOnly(recipe1.getName(), recipe2.getName());

        List<Menu> menus = menuRepository.findAll();
        Assertions.assertThat(menus).size().isEqualTo(1);

        Menu actualMenu = menus.get(0);
        Assertions.assertThat(actualMenu).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(actualMenu.getRecipes()).size().isEqualTo(2);
        Assertions.assertThat(actualMenu.getRecipes())
                .extracting("name")
                .containsOnly(recipe1.getName(), recipe2.getName());
    }
```

When I do `menuService.addRecipe(menu1.getId(), recipe2.getId());` first time second time in table `recipe2menu` there is single row (recipe_i - menu_id). But at second time I have 3 rows (1-1; 1-1; 1-2). But I expected only 2 because I added only twice. When I invoke `menuService.addRecipe(menu1.getId(), recipe2.getId());` one more time rows would be 6 (1-1; 1-1; 1-1; 1-1; 1-2; 1-3). Problem disapear when I don't add Products to recipes... The more Products are in Recipe the more rows is in `recipe2menu` table is created each time I add single recipe.

Breakpoint at `Menu menu1AfterAddRecipe = menuService.addRecipe(menu1.getId(), recipe3.getId());`:
[image]

I am using MySql.

Any ideas?

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Can't you just add new object which will map `recipe2menu`?
It will be easier to manage annotations.
On the other hand, maybe you should try with insertable/updatable as false in `@JoinColumn` annotation?

Comment: I want to omit this. I don't want to create class only for associate table.

Comment: I changed my mind. I need class `recipe2menu`. I will keep `recipeid`, `menuid`, `menu_type` there. Many thanks!

Comment: But can't you just change updatable value?
Something like this: `@JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)`